# ReadAsMultipartAsync not works

Tags: c#, .net, http

I want know if anyone know because is happening this:

*This not works:*

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void AddFile()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }            

    var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider();
    Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ....
    });
}
```

*But this if it works(**is the the correct solution?**):*

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public Task AddFile()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }            

    var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider();
    return Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ....
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you are not processing the returned task from `ReadAsMultipartAsync`. The method immediately exits.

In the second example, you give the task to the base class, which handles the task for you and waits for it's execution.

If you do not want to return the task, e.g. if you want to do something after it finishes, you can mark your method as `async` and `await` the task like so:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public async Task AddFile()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }            

    var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider();
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        ....
    });
}
```

Comment: Mixing ContinueWith and async/await leads to problems, just do `await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);` and everything in the `.ContinueWith` would just go after the `await` like normal code.

Comment: But I am using .NET 4.0, and cannot do this. I believe that is better use just return.

Comment: If returning works for you, it's fine. Otherwise you can take a look at this package, it basically adds async/await support to .NET 4.0 www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async